# Gson - convert from Json to a typed ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Using the Gson library, how do I convert a JSON string to an `ArrayList` of a custom class `JsonLog`? Basically, `JsonLog` is an interface implemented by different kinds of logs made by my Android app--SMS logs, call logs, data logs--and this `ArrayList` is a collection of all of them. I keep getting an error in line 6.

```
public static void log(File destination, JsonLog log) {
    Collection<JsonLog> logs = null;
    if (destination.exists()) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(destination));
        logs = gson.fromJson(br, ArrayList<JsonLog>.class); // line 6
        // logs.add(log);
        // serialize "logs" again
    }
}
```

It seems the compiler doesn't understand I'm referring to a typed `ArrayList`. What do I do?

Comment: Please also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589381/how-to-convert-json-string-into-list-of-java-object/50903714#50903714 for another approach

Answer (score 614, accepted):

You may use [TypeToken](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to load the json string into a custom object.

```
logs = gson.fromJson(br, new TypeToken<List<JsonLog>>(){}.getType());
```

**Documentation:**

> Represents a generic type **T**.
>
> Java doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this class does. Forces clients to create a subclass of this class which enables retrieval the type information even at runtime.
>
> For example, to create a type literal for `List<String>`, you can create an empty anonymous inner class:
>
> `TypeToken<List<String>> list = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {};`
>
> This syntax cannot be used to create type literals that have wildcard parameters, such as `Class<?>` or `List<? extends CharSequence>`.

**Kotlin:**

If you need to do it in **Kotlin** you can do it like this:

```
val myType = object : TypeToken<List<JsonLong>>() {}.type
val logs = gson.fromJson<List<JsonLong>>(br, myType)
```

Or you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381385/20634) for various alternatives.

Comment: tried this approach and i got a compile error saying TypeToken() has protected access only

Comment: @jonney I have the same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: if you are getting has protected access error, you left out the `{ }` before `.getType()`

Comment: @Alex  does it deserialize first to an Array then that Array is converted into List or does it directly deserialize to List ?

Comment: Wholly cow!  I would have figured that like...well...never.  Thank you.

Comment: To me this looked like "whatever it is, it will NEVER work". It worked. Now I really need to take some time to understand it. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Is there an explanation to this?

Comment: @Ab_ take a look at the TypeToken documentation, it explain what it does: https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html

Comment: Kotlin instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381384/how-to-use-typetoken-generics-with-gson-in-kotlin

Comment: Been coming back to this reply once in a while. But, Kotlin example was a cherry on the icing!

Answer (score 30):

Your JSON sample is:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "comment": "",
    "result": {
    "id": 276,
    "firstName": "mohamed",
    "lastName": "hussien",
    "players": [
            "player 1",
            "player 2",
            "player 3",
            "player 4",
            "player 5"
    ]
}
```

so if you want to save arraylist of modules in your SharedPrefrences so :

1- will convert your returned arraylist for json format using this method

```
public static String toJson(Object jsonObject) {
    return new Gson().toJson(jsonObject);
}
```

2- Save it in shared prefreneces

```
PreferencesUtils.getInstance(context).setString("players", toJson((.....ArrayList you want to convert.....)));
```

3- to retrieve it at any time get JsonString from Shared preferences like that

```
String playersString= PreferencesUtils.getInstance(this).getString("players");
```

4- convert it again to array list

```
public static Object fromJson(String jsonString, Type type) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
}

ArrayList<String> playersList= (ArrayList<String>) fromJson(playersString,
                    new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    }.getType());
```

this solution also doable if you want to parse ArrayList of Objects
Hope it's help you by using [Gson Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) .

Comment: this is the correct solution, but essentially the same as the three years older answer with a lot of unneccessary information - I didn't come here to learn about sharedPreferences

Answer (score 14):

Why nobody wrote this **simple way of converting JSON string in List** ?

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(jsonString, Object[].class));
```

Comment: Because the poster wants the list to be a specific type. It's literally right there in the title of the question. Also, you can just use `new Gson()` instead of `new GsonBuilder().create()`.

Answer (score 12):

> Kotlin

```
data class Player(val name : String, val surname: String)

val json = [
  {
    "name": "name 1",
    "surname": "surname 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 2",
    "surname": "surname 2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 3",
    "surname": "surname 3"
  }
]

val typeToken = object : TypeToken<List<Player>>() {}.type
val playerArray = Gson().fromJson<List<Player>>(json, typeToken)
```

**OR**

```
val playerArray = Gson().fromJson(json, Array<Player>::class.java)
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use Arrays, it's pretty simple.

```
logs = gson.fromJson(br, JsonLog[].class); // line 6
```

Provide the `JsonLog` as an array `JsonLog[].class`

Answer (score 8):

If you want convert from Json to a typed ArrayList , it's wrong to specify the type of the object contained in the list. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); 
 List<MyClass> myList = gson.fromJson(inputString, ArrayList.class);
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's say, You have a **string** like this.

```
"[{"id":2550,"cityName":"Langkawi","hotelName":"favehotel Cenang Beach - Langkawi","hotelId":"H1266070"},
{"id":2551,"cityName":"Kuala Lumpur","hotelName":"Metro Hotel Bukit Bintang","hotelId":"H835758"}]"
```

Then you can covert it to **ArrayList** via **Gson** like

```
var hotels = Gson().fromJson(historyItem.hotels, Array<HotelInfo>::class.java).toList()
```

Your **HotelInfo** class should like this.

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json

data class HotelInfo(

    @Json(name="cityName")
    val cityName: String? = null,

    @Json(name="id")
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Json(name="hotelId")
    val hotelId: String? = null,

    @Json(name="hotelName")
    val hotelName: String? = null
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about gson but this is how you do it with Jon.sample hope there must be similar way using gson

{
        "Players": [
                "player 1",
                "player 2",
                "player 3",
                "player 4",
                "player 5"
        ]
    }

===============================================

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JosnFileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String jsonfile ="fileloaction/fileName.json";


                FileReader reader = null;
                JSONObject jsb = null;
                try {
                    reader = new FileReader(jsonfile);
                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                     jsb = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new Exception(e);
                } finally {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                }
                List<String> Players=(List<String>) jsb.get("Players");
                for (String player : Players) {
                    System.out.println(player);
                }           
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Sagar Zala :what's example you are expecting ..?

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin**
**For sending : If you send Arraylist**

```
Gson().toJson(arraylist)
```

**For receiving: If you receive ArrayList**

```
var arraylist = Gson().fromJson(argument, object : TypeToken<ArrayList<LatLng>>() {}.type)
```

**For sending : If you send ModelClass( e.g. LatLngModel.class)**

```
var latlngmodel = LatlngModel()
latlngmodel.lat = 32.0154
latlngmodel.lng = 70.1254

Gson().toJson(latlngModel)
```

**For receiving: If you receive ModelClass**

```
var arraylist = Gson().fromJson(argument,LatLngModel::class.java )
```