# How to store json values into array

Tags: android, google-maps

I used JSON to receive data from web perfectly but I want to use longitude and latitude which i stored in database then want to use in `MapActivty` so I want to store all the values in a simple array to play with it in MapActivity

```
ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
                Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
                String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
                // print the json response in the log
                Log.d("Get match fixture resps","> " + json);
                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("try", "in the try");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                        Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                        Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                        int len = matchFixture.length();
                        Log.d("len", "get array length");
                        for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                            String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
                            Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                            String teamA = c.getString(TAG_TEAMA);
                            Log.d("teamA", teamA);
                            String teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                            Log.d("teamB", teamB);`
```

Comment: Could you please provide your JSON structure sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using GSON or Jackson to convert back and for from Java/JSON.

> GSON - based on an existing answer

[Gson - convert from Json to a typed ArrayList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt)

```
arrayFromJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Pair<Float,Float>>(){}.getType());
```

Google Maps APIs has a LatLng object that is a Pair so you may want to try.

```
arrayFromJson = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<LatLng>(){}.getType());
```

Then you can add markers with:

```
for (LatLng latlng: arrayFromJSON) {

  Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(latlng)
                      .draggable(true));
}
```

You may want to check out: [Google Maps Example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java) to see how it all works together.

Comment: i got data in array sir how can i send this data to MapActivity