# Symfony 3 JSONResponse on Android

Tags: php, android, json, symfony

so im using a createQuery to connect to my symfony database with Doctrine like this

```
// JSON ACTION
public function jsonAction()
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT pa FROM CBMedBundle:Patients pa');
$myArray = $query->getArrayResult();
return new JsonResponse($myArray);
}
```

At url : http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/json
Now i want to export the result (jsonreponse) on Android (eclipse android) and show the response there !
How can i do that ?

I found this code on google about showing a json code on Android but i don't know how to adapt it for my problem . Thanks

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView t;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         t.setText(getServerData(strURL));
        }
         public static final String strURL = "http://10.0.2.2/connexion.php";

         private String getServerData(String returnString) {
             InputStream is = null;
             String result ="";

             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePaires = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             nameValuePaires.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tblville","tblville"));
             // Envoie de la commande Http
             try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strURL);
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePaires));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();
         }
         catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection "+e.toString());
           }


         //conversion de la réponse en chaine de caractère
            try
            {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

             StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

             String line = null;

             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
             {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
             }

             is.close();

             result = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
             Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result"+e.toString());
            }
            //recuperation des donnees json
            try{
              JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                 {

                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       Log.i("log_tag","ID_ville : "+json_data.getString("ID_ville")+" , Nom_ville : "+json_data.getString("Nom_ville")
                               );
                        returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                }
            }
                catch(JSONException e){
                 Log.e("log_tag","Error Parsing data"+e.toString());
                } 
                return returnString;

    }
    }
```

EDIT : The JSONresponse Result

```
[{"id":1,"nom":"Kane","prenom":"Samba","DateNaissance":{"date":"1995-03-08     00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"LieudeNaissance":"Nouakchott","sexe":"Homme","adresse":"Tunis","profession":"Etudiant","NumerodeTel":"+21629760962","Email":"kane_samba4@yahoo.fr","SituationFamilial":"Mari\u00e9"},{"id":2,"nom":"Bebeskho","prenom":"AllStar","DateNaissance":{"date":"1995-02-08 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"LieudeNaissance":"Bamako","sexe":"Homme","adresse":"Tunis","profession":"Cuisinier","NumerodeTel":"+2167583486","Email":"bebeskho@gmail.com","SituationFamilial":"C\u00e9libataire"},{"id":3,"nom":"Vecenzo","prenom":"Gaimno","DateNaissance":{"date":"1995-01-01 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"LieudeNaissance":"Tunis","sexe":"Homme","adresse":"Ariana","profession":"Etudiant","NumerodeTel":"+21654758","Email":"vecenzogo","SituationFamilial":"Mari\u00e9"},{"id":4,"nom":"Diara","prenom":"Bakary","DateNaissance":{"date":"1995-06-10 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"},"LieudeNaissance":"Dakar","sexe":"Homme","adresse":"Dakar Sacr\u00e9 Coeur","profession":"Etudiant","NumerodeTel":"+2214753526","Email":"diaBakis@gmail.com","SituationFamilial":"C\u00e9libataire"}]
```

[JsonResponse Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH3Cu.png)

Now , i just want to show this result on my Android emulator application (eclipse)

Comment: Can you paste the JSON response that your server generates? You'd want to parse this JSON in your Android code  -so it will help us to see how it looks like and we can advise you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adapt the code for your purposes - you need to change the URL to point to your server. Change `public static final String strURL = "http://10.0.2.2/connexion.php";` to something like `http://<your-server-ip-address>/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/json` (I am assuming HTTP-GET request returns the JSON array you pasted). You then modify the JSON processing code to extract details that are contained in your JSON file - like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
     {

        JSONObject personJSONData= jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = personJSONData.getString("id");
        String nom = personJSONData.getString("nom");
        //do the same for the other attributes
        //note that according to your JSON file, DateNaissance is a JSONObject - so you have to do something like
       JSONObject dateNaissanceObject = personJSONData.getJSONObject("DateNaissance");

 }
```

But I'd really recommend that you use something like Gson to parse the incoming JSON payload into a list of "Person" objects, for instance. As an example, and assuming you have created a Person class, you'd do this:

`List<Person> persons = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType());`
. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt) is a nice example of this - and [here](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) is another nice example using Gson - there's also a good tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html).