# How to convert ArrayList of Point stored in file as string to Arraylist object using Gson?

Tags: java, android, gson

I have Arraylist of Points object stored in file as a string. I converted it into string using gson library.

```
for (final VisionDetRet ret : results) {
    ArrayList<Point> landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"fileName.txt", true);
    gson.toJson(landmarks, writer);
    writer.close();
}
```

This store list of points in file like

```
[{"X":90, "Y":120},{"X":50, "Y":121},...][{"X":90, "Y":120},
{"X":50, "Y":121},...][{"X":90, "Y":120},{"X":50, "Y":121},...]
```

I want to read string from that file and want to convert back into ArrayList.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson - convert from Json to a typed ArrayList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a TypeToken for the `ArrayList` with the specific generic type defined.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"fileName.txt");

Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Point>>() { }.getType();

ArrayList<Point> landmarks = new Gson().fromJson(reader, listType);
```