# Covert an array from javascript to JSONArray in java

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, json

I am having an array in javascript which is a bit lengthy as shown

```
var array = [
      {min: 0, max: 5000, init: 155.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 5001, max: 20000, init: 171.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 20001, max: 40000, init: 188.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 40001, max: 50000, init: 264.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 50001, max: 60000, init: 341.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 60001, max: 70000, init: 419.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 70001, max: 80000, init: 496.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 80001, max: 90000, init: 574.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 90001, max: 100000, init: 651.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 100001, max: 110000, init: 729.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 110001, max: 120000, init: 806.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 120001, max: 130000, init: 884.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 130001, max: 140000, init: 961.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 140001, max: 150000, init: 1039.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 150001, max: 160000, init: 1116.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 160001, max: 170000, init: 1194.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 170001, max: 180000, init: 1271.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 180001, max: 190000, init: 1349.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 190001, max: 200000, init: 1426.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 200001, max: 210000, init: 1504.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 210001, max: 220000, init: 1581.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 220001, max: 230000, init: 1659.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 230001, max: 240000, init: 1736.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 240001, max: 250000, init: 1814.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 250001, max: 260000, init: 1891.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 260001, max: 270000, init: 1969.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 270001, max: 280000, init: 2046.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 280001, max: 290000, init: 2124.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 290001, max: 300000, init: 2201.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 300001, max: 310000, init: 2279.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 310001, max: 320000, init: 2356.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 320001, max: 330000, init: 2434.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 330001, max: 340000, init: 2511.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 340001, max: 350000, init: 2589.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 350001, max: 360000, init: 2666.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 360001, max: 370000, init: 2744.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 370001, max: 380000, init: 2821.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 380001, max: 390000, init: 2899.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 390001, max: 400000, init: 2976.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 400001, max: 410000, init: 3054.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 410001, max: 420000, init: 3131.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 420001, max: 430000, init: 3209.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 430001, max: 440000, init: 3286.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 440001, max: 450000, init: 3364.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 450001, max: 460000, init: 3441.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 460001, max: 470000, init: 3519.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 470001, max: 480000, init: 3596.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 480001, max: 490000, init: 3674.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 490001, max: 500000, init: 3751.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 500001, max: 510000, init: 3829.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 510001, max: 520000, init: 3906.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 520001, max: 530000, init: 3984.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 530001, max: 540000, init: 4061.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 540001, max: 550000, init: 4139.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 550001, max: 560000, init: 4216.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 560001, max: 570000, init: 4294.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 570001, max: 580000, init: 4371.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 580001, max: 590000, init: 4449.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 590001, max: 600000, init: 4526.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 600001, max: 610000, init: 4604.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 610001, max: 620000, init: 4681.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 620001, max: 630000, init: 4759.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 630001, max: 640000, init: 4836.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 640001, max: 650000, init: 4914.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 650001, max: 660000, init: 4991.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 660001, max: 670000, init: 5069.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 670001, max: 680000, init: 5146.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 680001, max: 690000, init: 5224.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 690001, max: 700000, init: 5301.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 700001, max: 710000, init: 5379.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 710001, max: 720000, init: 5456.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 720001, max: 730000, init: 5534.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 730001, max: 740000, init: 5611.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 740001, max: 750000, init: 5689.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 750001, max: 760000, init: 5766.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 760001, max: 770000, init: 5844.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 770001, max: 780000, init: 5921.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 780001, max: 790000, init: 5999.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 790001, max: 800000, init: 6076.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 800001, max: 810000, init: 6154.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 810001, max: 820000, init: 6231.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 820001, max: 830000, init: 6309.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 830001, max: 840000, init: 6386.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 840001, max: 850000, init: 6464.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 850001, max: 860000, init: 6541.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 860001, max: 870000, init: 6619.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 870001, max: 880000, init: 6696.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 880001, max: 890000, init: 6774.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 890001, max: 900000, init: 6851.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 900001, max: 910000, init: 6929.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 910001, max: 920000, init: 7006.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 920001, max: 930000, init: 7084.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 930001, max: 940000, init: 7161.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 940001, max: 950000, init: 7239.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 950001, max: 960000, init: 7316.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 960001, max: 970000, init: 7394.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 970001, max: 980000, init: 7471.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 980001, max: 990000, init: 7549.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 990001, max: 1000000, init: 7626.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 1000001, max: 1010000, init: 7704.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 1010001, max: 1020000, init: 7781.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 1020001, max: 1030000, init: 7859.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 1030001, max: 1040000, init: 7936.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 1040001, max: 1050000, init: 8014.00, plus: 0},
      {min: 1050001, max: 1060000, init: 8091.50, plus: 0},
      {min: 1060001, max: THRESHOLD_INF, init: 8169.00, plus: 0}
    ];
```

I need is to take this data to an android project. So what i know is typing each json object individually and add those objects to the array. It will look something like this

```
   `JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject one=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject two=new JSONObject();
    JSONObject three=new JSONObject();
    ...
     array.put(one);
     array.put(two);
     array.put(three);//and so on..
```

So, Since there a lot of objects to add manually, Is there any method by which i can convert this json array from javascript form to a JSONArray in java?

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(array.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String min = json.getString("min");
                    String max = json.getString("max");
                    //all other data will fetch here
                    array.put(json);
                }
```

try this code

Comment: while converting it with JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(array.toString()); , the string array.toString() should follow some rules to avoid json exception ryt? like each key value must have a double quote and so.. So how could i convert it to such a string ?

Comment: I dont think so you need something. Please try and check this code. If this crashes then show me crash report will help you

Comment: or try array[0].tostring() if any problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Google Gson Library for that they provide lot's of service including this.

Comment: Could you please provide an example in your answer for better understanding?

Comment: here is the full example : https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/convert-json-array-to-arraylist-gson/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt

Comment: While the link may have the required parts, it is better to add it in your answer. In the future, if the link gets modified or if it is not accessible from certain networks, it would be of no use to the future visitors. Add the relevant part in your answer and provide the link as a future reference.