# Add new element in a file

Tags: java, android, json, gson

mycode:

```
try {
        FileInputStream inputStream1 = getActivity().openFileInput("filename");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream1));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {total.append(line);}
        b.close();
        inputStream1.close();

    String json = total.toString();

    Items oldItems = new Gson().fromJson(json,Items.class);
    Items newItem = new Items();
    newItem.setName(example.getName());
    List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
    items.add(oldItems);
    items.add(newItem);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String itemsJson = gson.toJson(items);

    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream =  getActivity().openFileOutput("filename", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(itemsJson.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        Items newItem = new Items();
        newItem.setItem(example.getName());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(newItem);
        FileOutputStream outputStream =  getActivity().openFileOutput("filename", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception d) {
        d.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a code that read and write json in a file. I have no problem writing this:

```
[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}]
```

but when i try to read it for add a new "item" i have an error.
My idea is to add a new item when I click the button.
I don't understand what is the problem and how i can fix this problem.

Items.java

```
class Items implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

public String getName() { return name;}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

EDIT
The error is this:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: edit your question to add the error, but mostly it will be from this line `Items oldItems = new Gson().fromJson(json,Items.class);` you are deserialize the JSON as item, while it's an Array (list)

Comment: Can you add one or two lines of file content how it looks like? Does each line in the file contain one `Item` ?

Comment: yeah every row contains one Item

Comment: as i told you `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` you need something like `List<Items> oldItems = new Gson()...`  have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt

Comment: I've already tried but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

As you are using **GSON PARSER**

That works for me perfect-

```
String json = "[{\"name\":\"a\"},{\"name\":\"b\"}]";

        List<Items> writenItems =  new Gson()
                .fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Items>>(){}.getType());
                 writenItems
                .forEach($->
                 System.out.println("name: " + $.getName()));
```

Comment: I read that post but it does not work yet..
can you be more specific ? i do

Comment: can you show me the code where you call the gson parsing? or you have the exception on the line where you try to write it?

Comment: the error is here:
Items oldItems = new Gson().fromJson(json,Items.class);
What I should show? i'm confused

Comment: read my updated answer. if it does not work for you - it is from the writer. but test my code and you will see it working- parsing the string you are stating you have

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing your json to file, can you write it in this format ?

[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"}], that is with double quotes surrounding the name key.

It should resolve this issue.

thanks

Comment: Ohh, that is what I noticed as it was invalid JSON format :-)