# How to deserialize a JSON file ( using Google JSON) consisting of same key name but uses different type?

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

Consider the following JSON File:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "firstData": {
        "meta": "this is string",
        "version": "1"
    },
    "SecondData": {
        "meta": ["string1", "string2", "string3"],
        "version": "1"
    },
    "ThirdData": {
        "meta": true,
        "version": "1"
    },
    "FourthData": {
        "meta": [true, false, false, true],
        "version": "1"
    },
    "FifthData": {
        "meta": [{
            "meta": "string",
            "version": "2"
        },
        {
            "meta": ["string1","string2"],
            "version": "2"
        }]
        "version": "1"
    }

}
```

As seen, The "meta" attribute has different data type, sometimes it is String, sometimes it is ArrayOfString, sometimes Boolean etc.

Since my JSON file has several data,
I want it to follow the following Structure :

```
class information
{
String version;
HashMap<String,Data> details;
}
class Data
{
 variable meta;
String version;
}
```

How do I create a corresponding POJO and deserialize it using Google GSON?

Comment: Also, there are few things that are unclear about this, can this go to any level of nesting for the `meta` element, is that a consideration ? I see the fifth element is a json object which has meta as well, does that mean nesting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your `meta` as `JsonElement`. Then you will have sort methods like: `getAsString`, `getAsBoolean`, `getAsJsonObject`, `getAsJsonArray`, ..., and also you are able to deserialize it again after you find out what is the type.

So your class could look like:

```java
public class SomeClass {
    private int version;
    private JsonElement meta;

    //getters and setters and other stuff
}
```

#### Edit: More elaboration and implementation

Define two classes: `GeneralItem` and `GeneralData`

```java
class GeneralItem
{
    public final int version;
    public final JsonElement meta;
}
```

```java
class GeneralData
{
    public final String version;
    public final Map<String, GeneralItem> items;

    public GeneralData(String version, Map<String, GeneralItem> items)
    {
        this.version = version;
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

And then we define a custom deserializer for our `GeneralData`:

```java
class GeneralDataDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<GeneralData>
{

    @Override
    public GeneralData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        final JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
        final String version = object.get("version").getAsString();
        object.remove("version");
        HashMap<String, GeneralItem> items = new HashMap<>(object.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> item : object.entrySet())
            items.put(item.getKey(), context.deserialize(item.getValue(), GeneralItem.class));
        return new GeneralData(version, items);
    }
}
```

Finally registering the deserializer to our gson instance and getting the data:

```java
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(GeneralData.class, new GeneralDataDeserializer())
        .create();

final String json = "your json here";
final GeneralData data = gson.fromJson(json, GeneralData.class);
System.out.println(data.items.get("firstData").meta.getAsString());
//other parts you want
```

(Note that constructors, getter and setters, error checking, etc. are removed for the sake of brevity)

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Thank you for the response, However I didn't understand it. Can you elaborate it please or perhaps share the solution using GSON

Comment: It is GSON! you need to just define your `firstData`, `SecondData`, ... as `SomeClass` (name it anything you like) and then they will be deserialized and then you can call `meta.getAsString()` for `firstData`, or `meta.getAsJsonArray()` for `SecondData`.
Let me know if you want more examples.

Comment: Yes, Correct, But what if i have firstData,SecondData.......ThousandthData..Thats why Instead of creating so many classes, I want to create a map of string to a single class structure, as described above, can you help me in that?

Comment: I have provided more information if you want to check. @coder

Comment: I have one doubt, the Meta will be stored as JSONElement. If its a String Array, It wont be stored as String Array. Is there a way to store them as the corresponding data type?

Comment: You can change type of `meta` to `Object`. Then for gson primitive types like `int`, `String`, `boolean`, etc. it will be filled with expected value with that java type; for son arrays, it will be filled with an `ArrayList` of those primitive types, and for objects (like FirfthData) `meta` will be a `Map` of `String` to those primitive types. @coder

Comment: Yes, I was able to retain the original type. Although, what if the meta is basically an array of objects of metas? check the JSON file FifthData above^

Comment: It'll give you a list of maps. If you want to get the objects, you can do the deserialization manually and provide the type. If deserializing an `ArrayList` of meta is question for you, you can search for deserializing generic types by gson.

Comment: The code you wrote handles all the data types of meta except ArrayList<Meta>?
How to handle that?, can you please edit your response and add the solution there? I tried but i could not solve it!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384064/gson-convert-from-json-to-a-typed-arraylistt